# C++11 lambda returning reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have some trouble to return a reference from a lambda. 
This code works :

```
std::function<int*(int*)> funct;

funct = [](int *i){
    ++*i;
    return i;
};

int j = 0;
LOG<<*funct(&j)<<j;
```

Output : 1 1

But not this one :

```
std::function<int&(int&)> funct;

funct = [](int &i){
    ++i;
    return i;
};

int j = 0;
LOG<<funct(j)<<j;
```

Building error : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\type_traits:1441: error: C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'int &'

Any idea why? For me it is the same thing.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE]. Your current one doesn't compile.

Comment: Why would you want to return it as a reference? What is the problem that is supposed to solve? Why not simply return it by value (which is what the lambda already does)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because it gets it as reference by parameter. For example chained `std::ostream::operator<<` invocations.

Comment: @Slava It's not needed for chaining `<<`. The only reason I could see is if the "call" was used as the left-hand side of an assignment. I don't see much of a use-case or purpose for that here though, which is why I wonder what problem it's supposed to solve. This question is simply [a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Note that you modify and read `j` without sequenced point.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It needs to return a reference because the `std::function` signature requires it. So I guess you would then ask why give the `std::function` that signature? Who cares. Returning a reference is a common enough requirement that we don't need to question users every time the ask how to do it. And providing the context in which he is using this `std::function` would just be noise in the question.

Comment: @Jarod42: There is a sequence point. It is indeterminate though. The function body must occur either before or after the other read.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The lambda deduces the return type as if specified with `auto`. `auto ret = i;` would deduce `ret` to be an `int`.

One solution is to explicitly state the return type of the lambda:

```
funct = [](int &i) -> int& {
    ++i;
    return i;
};
```

As mentioned in the comments another way is

```
funct = [](int &i) -> decltype(auto) {
    ++i;
    return i;
};
```

which essentially tells the compiler not to do any deduction and to just use the type as if `decltype` had been used on the return expression.

If you are curious about the exact rules check [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) which also has a section on `auto` and a bit on `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: Or use `decltype(auto)` as return type! That is in contrast to the usage of `auto`. That is, `decltype(auto) ret = i;` makes `ret` as reference to `i`.

Comment: and people say c++ has obscure , complex syntax. What do they know :-)

Comment: Isn't auto& for return type does the same with decltype(auto) and more readable?

Comment: @CemKalyoncu I'd consider `int &` more readable, but I guess it's a matter of style. They do the same in this case, but not in general. When you have `[](auto &&i)` you need to check more carefully what type you want to return in which situation.

Comment: @nwp Of course, but when it is not something concise as int you may use auto.